# Bounds on the spherical measure of sub-level sets of quadratic forms

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, convex-geometry, eigenvalues

I'm wondering if there are any bounds on the spherical measure of sets of the form
$$
\mu_n\left(\{y\in S^{n-1} : \frac{y_1^2}{y_2^2} < \alpha\}\right) \leq f(\alpha)
$$
where $\alpha$ is some number less than 1.  More generally, for some symmetric matrix $A$ I'd be interested in bounds on spherically convex sets like
$$
\mu_n\left(\{y\in S^{n-1} : y^TAy < \alpha\}\right) \leq f(\alpha,\sigma(A)).
$$

In slightly more generality, what I'm really after is to say that if $a$ is a centered random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}[aa^T]=Id_{n\times n}$ then
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[a^TAa < \alpha\right] 
$$
is small.  I might need some extra assumptions on the distribution to use the spherical results.  Any references or insights would be helpful.

**EDIT:** As the first quantity only depends on the projection onto a two dimensional plane, it ends up being easy to compute the measures and see that it is dimension independent.

Comment: The magic word is spherical cap.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas is that really it though?  Will the first $f(\alpha) \approx e^{-c(\alpha)n}$?  That isn't obvious to me.